# Xamarin.Forms with SQLite won't build

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use SQLite on my project but it's not working. I can't build it after adding the packages and classes. Here's the output:

[image]

I installed the package sqlite-net-pcl as recommended here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and I followed this tutorial by the letter, still it's not working.

The only way it works is if I add the compiler option `-dlsym=yes` for MonoTouch. Is this the proper way to go? Wouldn't I be losing any features due to this?

Any ideias?

Comment: What are your linker settings? Device or simulator?

Comment: @valdetero device :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what datamodel you are using (code first or model first), but I also use SQLite with Xamarin.Forms and installed it as the following:

Added this nuget packages to my .Net Standard Library: (and my .iOS and .Andorid app)

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

To create the database I used this class (put in the Xamarin.Forms .Net Standard Library)

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The constructor for the database
    /// </summary>
    public MyDatabaseContext()
    {
        _path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", "Monitoring_Tool_LocalDb.db"); // For iOS, test with #if _IOS
        //_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Monitoring_Tool_LocalDb.db"); // For Android
        //_path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "exrin.db"); // For uwp
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The path where the database is saved
    /// </summary>
    private string _path = string.Empty;
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration for the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="optionsBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_path}");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // Your ModelBuilder modifications
    }
}
```

This also allows you to use all normal entity framework functions without problems.

Have a nice day c:

***Edit 1:***

I had named the constructor wrong, sorry therefore, just fixed this.

I also added the uwp connection string and here I found a good tutorial how to set this up properly: https://xamarinhelp.com/entity-framework-core-xamarin-forms/